# Restriction of the cotangent bundle to a rational normal curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a rational normal curve in $\mathbb P^n$. Therefore $X$ can be thought of as the image of the standard veronese map $\gamma_n :\mathbb P^1 \to \mathbb P^n$. Then can we say that $\Omega_{\mathbb P^n}|_{X} \cong \gamma_{n*}(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(-n-1)^{\oplus n})$?

We have two short exact sequences

$0 \to \Omega_{\mathbb P^n}|_{X} \to \mathcal O_X(-1)^{\oplus n+1} \to \mathcal O_X \to 0$ and $0 \to I/I^2 \to \Omega_{\mathbb P^n}|_{X} \to \Omega_X \to 0$

But I don't see how it follows from the above two exact sequences.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key observation is the vanishing of the cohomology of $\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)\vert_X$. To check this just use the restriction to $X$ of the Euler sequence
$$
0 \to \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)\vert_X \to
\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus (n+1)} \to \mathcal{O}_X(n) \to 0
$$
and note that by definition of the rational normal curve the second map is given by all monomials of degree $n$ in coordinates of $X$. Therefore, it induces an isomorphism of the cohomology, hence we have
$$
H^\bullet(X, \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)\vert_X) = 0.
$$
Finally, any vector bundle on $X$ is a direct sum of line bundles, and the only line bundle without cohomology is $\mathcal{O}_X(-1)$. Thus
$$
\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)\vert_X \cong \mathcal{O}_X(-1)^{\oplus n}.
$$

Comment: the third term of the first S.E.S should be $\mathcal O_X(1)$ instead of $\mathcal O_X(n)$ right? Could you please indicate briefly at exactly what point we start identifying $X$ with $\mathbb P^1$ and why from the last isomorphism the conclusion follows?

Comment: This is $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$ restricted to $X$; since the embedding of $X$ has degree $n$, it is $\mathcal{O}_X(n)$.

Comment: thanks for the explaination. Can we write $H^i(\mathbb P^1, \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(-1)) =H^i(X, \mathcal O_X(-n))$ using projection formula? and if the pullback of a vector bundle from $X$ to $\mathbb P^1$ splits into direct sum of line bundles, then is it trivial that  the original bundle on $X$ also splits?

Comment: In your notation $X$ is $\mathbb{P}^1$, right? Hence "no" for the first question.

Comment: Thanks. Here we are identifying $(X, \mathcal O_X(1))$ as $(\mathbb P^1, \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(n))$ right?